# Read text file line by line, divide into words in C

Tags: c, text, fopen, fgets

I'm trying to process some files. The file paths are stored in a txt file. There are 4 filenames per line, each separated with a space. I want to read a line into a buffer, divide the buffer into those 4 filepaths and process them afterwards. When I'm done, I want to do the same thing for the filepaths from the next line.

I have the following code to process the filenames:

```
int i, j, check, fileidx, filenum;
char buf[100000], *testfile;
char filename_out[500], filename_mess[500], filename_ref[500], filename_dark[500];

filenum = getFileNumber("filelist.txt"); //get number of lines in the txt file

filelist = fopen("filelist.txt","r");

for (fileidx=0; fileidx<filenum; fileidx++){
    memset(&filename_mess[0], 0, sizeof(filename_mess)); //clear filenames
    memset(&filename_dark[0], 0, sizeof(filename_dark));
    memset(&filename_ref[0], 0, sizeof(filename_ref));
    memset(&filename_out[0], 0, sizeof(filename_out));
    memset(&buf[0],0,sizeof(buf));

    for (check = 0;check<fileidx+1;check++){  //up to the current file index
        testfile = fgets(buf,100000,filelist); //get each line into the buffer
            if ((testfile == NULL)&(check == fileidx)){ //if at the correct file index and line is empty
                printf("Error in filelist (line %i is empty!)",check+1);
                goto fileerror;
            };
    };

    if (fileidx==filenum-1)
            sprintf(buf,"%s\0",buf); //desperate try - not helping

    if ((buf[0] == '\n') | (buf[0] == ' ') | (buf[0] == EOF)){
        printf("Error in filelist (line %i)!",fileidx+1);
        goto fileerror;
    };

    i=0;
    while (buf[i]!=' '){ //while not hitting the first space
        if (buf[i] == '\n'){ //if a filename is missing, the end of the line is found too early
            printf("Error in filelist (line %i)! Element missing!",fileidx+1);
            goto fileerror; //goto the next file
        };
        filename_mess[i] = buf[i]; //copy the buffer to the first filename array
        i++;
    };
    i++; //skip the space between the filepaths
    j = i; //save start of second filepath
    while (buf[i]!=' '){ //repeat the process for second filename
        if (buf[i] == '\n'){
            printf("Error in filelist (line %i)! Element missing!",fileidx+1);
            goto fileerror;
        };
        filename_ref[i-j] = buf[i];
        i++;
    };
    i++;
    j = i;
    while (buf[i]!=' '){ //repeat process for third filename
        if (buf[i] == '\n'){
            printf("Error in filelist (line %i)! Element missing!",fileidx+1);
            goto fileerror;
        };
        filename_dark[i-j] = buf[i];
        i++;
    };
    i++;
    j = i;
    while ((buf[i]!='\n') & (buf[i]!= EOF) & (buf[i]!=' ')){ //we're at the last element, check for end of line or EOF here, too
        if (buf[i] == ' '){
            printf("Error in filelist (line %i)! Too many elements!",fileidx+1);
            goto fileerror;
        };
        filename_out[i-j] = buf[i];
        i++;
    };


//read the files, process them

};
```

This code works perfectly fine for all the lines except for the last one. In the last line, only the last element is stored in "filename_out", the others (mess,ref and dark) remain empty. The buffer "buf" looks fine, tho (checking it with `printf("%s",buf)` shows the expected line). When I add an empty line below my last line in the text file, the reading works fine. I also tried to use `sprintf(buf,"%s\n",buf)` to add this (seemingly necessary) character to the buffer each time - didnt work.

To clarify: reading a txt file containing

```
R1E1 R1E2 R1E3 R1E4
R2E1 R2E2 R2E3 R2E4
```

Will give me:

```
File1:
filename_mess = R1E1
filename_ref = R1E2
filename_dark = R1E3
filename_out = R1E4

File2:
filename_mess = 
filename_ref = 
filename_dark = 
filename_out = R2E4
```

While it should be:

```
File1:
filename_mess = R1E1
filename_ref = R1E2
filename_dark = R1E3
filename_out = R1E4

File2:
filename_mess = R2E1
filename_ref = R2E2
filename_dark = R2E3
filename_out = R2E4
```

Adding a blank line to the end of the text file will return:

```
File1:
filename_mess = R1E1
filename_ref = R1E2
filename_dark = R1E3
filename_out = R1E4

File2:
filename_mess = R2E1
filename_ref = R2E2
filename_dark = R2E3
filename_out = R2E4

File3:
*Error Message*
```

Edit: removed some errors.

Comment: Among the many incorrect/questionable things in this code, `while (buf[i]!=' ')` - `buf[i]` is `char*`, you're comparing it against a char literal. Max out your compiler warning levels, because there are *many* flagged in this. It at-least-appears like `buf` should be a `char` array, not a `char*` array.

Comment: That's an error in the code here, sorry. It actually is `char`.

Comment: When posting code, please copy/paste the *real* code after reducing it to a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem. Copy/paste = no typos.

Comment: And since you don't need to retain the fnames from line to line (this code certainly doesn't), this can be made [considerably simpler](http://ideone.com/PlqROf).

Answer (score 0):

```
for (fileidx=0; fileidx<filenum-1; fileidx++)
```

Does this work for one line files? Shouldn't there be <= ?

Comment: How about simply `fileidx < filenum`

Comment: Wow, another error here. I'm sorry. The -1 isn't there in the acutual code. But yes, it does 'work' for one line files. With the same error occuring. To read only one file, I'd need to add a blank line below. Else it's only reading the last filepath and ignores the first three for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `buf[i]== EOF` did work. Add `'\n'` to the end of each `buf` and check for `buf[i]=='\n'` instead of `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the link at [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/FILE/) at cplusplus reference which describes the straight forward way of reading lines from a file in sequence.

And this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/?kw=strtok) also at cplusplus reference describes the straight forward way of tokenizing a string based on delimiters (to split the line to 4 separate strings)

using these links I managed to put together the following code that seems to do what you want

```
//#include "file_processor_main_stackoverflow_question.h" //this is my own stuff
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>


static void parse_line(char *line, char *res[], const int n_words, const int word_length);

int file_processor_so_main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n_words = 4;
    int word_length = 1000;

    FILE *f = NULL;
    char buf[9999];

    printf("file processor main\n");
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: file_processor [file_name]\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!f) {
      printf("failed to open file: %s\n", argv[1]);
      return 0;
    }

    //file was opened successfully

    while (!feof(f)) {
      int i; char *res[4];
      if (fgets(buf, 9999, f) == NULL)
        break;
      printf("buf: %s\n", buf);
      //initialize res
      for (i = 0; i < n_words; ++i) {
        res[i] = (char*)calloc(word_length, sizeof(char));
      }
      parse_line(buf, res, n_words, word_length);
      for (i = 0; i < n_words; ++i) {
        printf("res[%d]: %s\n", i, res[i]);
        //process file at res[i]
        free(res[i]);
      }
    }

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
  }

  void parse_line(char *line, char *res[], const int n_words, const int         word_length) {
    int count = 0;
    char *buf = strtok(line, " ");
    while (buf != NULL && count < n_words) {
      printf("%s ", buf);
      assert(strlen(buf) < word_length);
      strcpy(res[count++], buf);
      buf = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
```